# Get all characters of a string to the left of delimiter in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following are the queries I am running to fetch all the characters which  left to the `@` delimiter. I am not able to get the proper results. The number of characters to the left of delimiter are unknown.

```
select @class = SUBSTRING('25@class1', CHARINDEX('@','25@class1')-2, 8000)


select @class = left('25@class1',LEN('25@class1')-CHARINDEX('@','25@class1'))
```

Please help

Comment: You wanna get 25 or Class1?

Comment: That is invalid (standard) SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 5):

**Method 1**: (using `SUBSTRING`)

```
DECLARE @class VARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @class = SUBSTRING('25@class1', 1, CHARINDEX('@','25@class1') - 1)
```

**Method 2**: (using `LEFT`)

```
DECLARE @class VARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @class = LEFT('25@class1', CHARINDEX('@','25@class1') - 1)
```

**Method 3**: (using `STUFF`)

```
DECLARE @class VARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @class = STUFF('25@class1', CHARINDEX('@','25@class1'), (LEN('25@class1') - CHARINDEX('@','25@class1') + 1), '')
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to display before `@`. And also provided logic to find after and before `@`

```
declare @class varchar(200)
select @class = left('25@class1', CHARINDEX('@','25@class1')-1)

select @class  --before @

select @class = right('25@class1',len('25@class1')- CHARINDEX('@','25@class1'))
select @class -- after @
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @class VARCHAR(100) = '25@class1'
```

SELECT SUBSTRING(@class,0,CHARINDEX('@',@class))
SELECT LEN(SUBSTRING(@class,0,CHARINDEX('@',@class)))